# Binding property to visibility of other element

Tags: wpf, binding, visibility

I want when visibility of "StckPnl1" is set to Collapsed, my property "IsBusyIndicatorShowing" of "BusyDeco1" is being set to true.

What's the simplest solution?

```
    <ctrls:BusyDecorator x:Name="BusyDeco1" IsBusyIndicatorShowing="??" Style="{DynamicResource BusyDecorator1}"/>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StckPnl1" Visibility="Collapsed">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DataTrigger:

```
<ctrls:BusyDecorator>
    <ctrls:BusyDecorator.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrls:BusyDecorator}" BasedOn="{DynamicResource BusyDecorator1}">
            <Setter Property="IsBusyIndicatorShowing" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=StckPnl1, Path=Visibility}" Value="Collapsed">
                    <Setter Property="IsBusyIndicatorShowing" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ctrls:BusyDecorator.Style>
</ctrls:BusyDecorator>
```

Comment: @Gopichandar Thx for the heads-up, the SO didn't post code for `ctrls:BusyDecorator` so I used a TextBlock to double-check my code before posting and forgot to change the closing tags. Fixed now.

Comment: Thats ok.  Here is my +1 especially for `BaseOn`

Comment: Ok thanks I take this method, but I have changed "BasedOn = "{DynamicResource..." to "BasedOn = "{StaticResource..." because BasedOn is not compatible with DynamicResource

Answer (score 0):

i use a converter for this stuff.

```
<ctrls:BusyDecorator x:Name="BusyDeco1" 
 IsBusyIndicatorShowing="{Binding ElementName=StckPnl1, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource TrueIfNotVisibleConverter}}" Style="{DynamicResource BusyDecorator1}"/>
<StackPanel x:Name="StckPnl1" Visibility="Collapsed">


<Converter:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TrueIfVisibleConverter" Inverted="False" Not="False" />
<Converter:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TrueIfNotVisibleConverter" Inverted="False" Not="True" />
<Converter:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibleIfTrueConverter" Inverted="True" Not="False" />
<Converter:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibleIfNotTrueConverter" Inverted="True" Not="True" />


public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    private bool inverted = false;
    private bool not = false;

    public bool Inverted
    {
        get { return inverted; }
        set { inverted = value; }
    }

    public bool Not
    {
        get { return not; }
        set { not = value; }
    }


    private object VisibilityToBool(object value)
    {

        if (!(value is Visibility))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return (((Visibility)value) == Visibility.Visible) ^ Not;

    }

    private object BoolToVisibility(object value, object parameter)
    {

        if (!(value is bool))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        var hiddenodercollapsed = Visibility.Collapsed;
        if (parameter != null && parameter.ToString().ToLower().Contains("hidden"))
            hiddenodercollapsed = Visibility.Hidden;

        return ((bool)value ^ Not) ? Visibility.Visible : hiddenodercollapsed;
    }


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Inverted ? BoolToVisibility(value, parameter) : VisibilityToBool(value);

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Inverted ? VisibilityToBool(value) : BoolToVisibility(value, parameter);

    }
}
```